# How to prompt the user for a filename of the first and second files

Tags: python

I have tried to use the following script, however, this only prompts one input.

```py
from pathlib import Path
out_path = input('Filename A')
path = Path(out_path)

from pathlib import Path
out_path = input('Filename B')
path = Path(out_path)
```

Comment: you are maybe overriding the variable that stores the fole you want to use later?

Comment: You don't need to `from pathlib import Path` twice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "however, this only prompts one input." When I try this code, I see two messages, and the program expects me to give an input twice. If the problem is that you only have one stored Path afterwards, then yes, of course: whenever `=` is used, the name *stops* naming the old thing (if any), and names the new thing *instead*. So `path` will only store one Path. If the question is "how do I represent two paths in the same variable?", then use a list. If the question is "how do I represent two paths in separate variables?", then... just use separate variables.

Comment: Either way, you should probably follow through a tutorial or textbook and make sure you understand the fundamentals of the language. Running into a problem like this, not being able to fix it independently, and coming to Stack Overflow [as the first instinct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)... suggests a lack of understanding. Try not to copy and paste code and hope it works.